# Impure pipes instead of template function in angular

Tags: angular, getter, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I know using template function is not a good idea in angular. So in the projects which I have worked I was using pipes. But now I read an article which tells that we should use pure pipes to avoid change detection. So my question is, if we set pure as false and use that pipe instead of template function, does this both have the same change detection effect ? Only pure pipes should be used in this case?
And what about a getter function ? Does getter functions if we use in angular template, will not run change detection as normal template function ? Please some one help me with this, and if this is a stupid question, please forgive me. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is an example of an impure operation that you are currently using a function for?

Comment: I am displaying a list of items based on some variable value using pipes, and i set the pure: false

Comment: where are you getting the list of items from and does the list change based on 'some variable'?

Comment: My question is will impure pipes and template function cause same effect in change detection of angular ?

Answer (score 0):

**Impure Pipes**

An impure pipe will be called on every change detection cycle, the same as for a template function.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

*Impure pipes are called whenever change detection runs for a component, which could be as often as every few milliseconds.*

You should consider alternatives like preloading data, or if you really want to use a pipe, implement caching within it.

**Getters**

Getters will be called on every change detection cycle.

Refer to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyjwju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) where you can click the `Increment` button to cause change detection, and observe the console where you will see the console log from the `name` getter.

Comment: Getters will be called on every change detection cycle - so how does this better from normal template functions ?

Comment: They’re not better, as in my answer they are the same from a change detection POV.